# Correct way to delete double material on object by exact words inside

Tags: python

I try to excluding objects except 4 types, the objects in question have these letters in the name, but they are not always in the same place, for example ".Type1.001" to delete duplicate material , the script without the list work fine:

```
import bpy

mat_list = bpy.data.materials
scene = bpy.context.scene
obj_list = [".*Type", ".*AnotherType", ".*Example", ".*AnotherExample"]
patch_list = re.compile('|'.join(obj_list))

get_objs = [obj for obj in scene.objects if  obj.name == patch_list ]


for o in get_objs:
    for slot in o.material_slots:
        if slot.material.name[-3:].isnumeric():
            if slot.material.name[:-4] in mat_list:
                slot.material = mat_list[slot.material.name[:-4]]


return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Match the compiled `re`**

Not sure you will ever get `ob.name == patch_list` recommend using `patch_list.match(str)`

```
>>> "xxxxType1.001" == patch_list
False

>>> patch_list.match("xxxxType1.001")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='xxxxType1'>

>>> patch_list.match("xxxxType4.001")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='xxxxType4'>

>>> patch_list.match("xxxxTpe1.001")
>>> patch_list.match("xxxxTpe1.001") is None
True
```

In question code

```
import bpy
import re

scene = bpy.context.scene
obj_list = [".*Type%d" % i for i in range(1, 5)]
patch_list = re.compile('|'.join(obj_list))
get_objs = [o for o in scene.objects 
        if  patch_list.match(o.name)]
print(get_objs)
```

on your edit.  I'm not sure this changes anything.  Below I've simply added a names list of potential names of objects and how they match.

To repeat I dont think any object name is ever  going to be equal to a compiled `re` object.  `name == patch_list` hence your `get_objs` list will always be empty.

```
import re

obj_list = [".*Type", ".*AnotherType", ".*Example", ".*AnotherExample"]

namelist = ["SnoopType", "Frog", "DogisAnotherExample.001"]
patch_list = re.compile('|'.join(obj_list))

get_objs = [name for name in namelist if  patch_list.match(name)]

print(get_objs)
```

results in

```
['SnoopType', 'DogisAnotherExample.001']
```

Comment: forgive me, I asked the question incorrectly, because is an example but not have number list, now re edit my post so that everyone can understand better

Comment: That is the way ! Ty batFinger